# Cordova Background Mode plugin activated when Ionic camera open

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins, background-mode, cordova-plugin-camera

I'm using cordova background-mode plugin in my ionic app.

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

Alongside with bakcground mode i use ionic camera also. Every time device camera open, background mode is being **enable**

Is there any way to prevent background mode to be active when i open device camera from the app

Comment: can you put your code. what you mean by background mode get activate?

Comment: Inside app.component.ts i have this code
`platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.backgroundMode.enable();
})`

Then a function
`add_image(){
    this.camera.getPicture().then((ImageData) => {}
  }
`
When camera get open, app goes in background mode.

Comment: better to update your question...

Answer (score 0):

ionic, being a web app, the main layer uses a browser. When you open the camera, the layer submits to the device's camera. As a result background mode is activated since the ionic view has been removed.

Ideal for preventing this from turning off background mode on pages where you use the camera.